# Nex.js getStaticProps -- await multiple Firestore collections and return all as props?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a SPA whose index page has six components, each needing the data from a different Firestore collection. I'm able to successfully get the data in a useEffect() inside each component, but I'm wondering how I might await multiple Firestore collections in a single getStaticProps and return them all as props to the page and then pass each collection object to its respective component.

One prop to rule them all, as it were.

This doesn't work:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const adminData = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "admin")));
  const featuredData = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "featured")));
  const sidebarData = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "sidebar")));
  const watchNowData = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "watchNow")));
  const interviewsData = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "interviews")));
  const categoryData = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "category")));
  const headlinesData = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "headlines")));

 let admin = [];
  adminData.forEach((doc) => {
    admin.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
      timestamp: doc.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime(),
    });
  });
  let featured = [];
  featuredData.forEach((doc) => {
    featured.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
      timestamp: doc.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime(),
    });
  });
  let sidebar = [];
  sidebarData.forEach((doc) => {
    sidebar.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
      timestamp: doc.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime(),
    });
  });
  let watchNow = [];
  watchNowData.forEach((doc) => {
    watchNow.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
      timestamp: doc.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime(),
    });
  });
  let interviews = [];
  interviewsData.forEach((doc) => {
    interviews.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
      timestamp: doc.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime(),
    });
  });
  let category = [];
  categoryData.forEach((doc) => {
    category.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
      timestamp: doc.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime(),
    });
  });
  let headlines = [];
  headlinesData.forEach((doc) => {
    headlines.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
      timestamp: doc.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime(),
    });
  });

  return {
    props: {
      admin: admin,
      featured: featured,
      sidebar: sidebar,
      watchNow: watchNow,
      interviews: interviews,
      category: category,
      headlines: headlines,
    },
  };
}

export default function HomePage({...props}) {
   const [admin, featured, sidebar, watchNow, interviews, category, headlines] =
    props;

...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your promises are not dependent on each other, you can use `Promise.all()` and actually this is the exact situation where `Promise.all()` excels (Note: Do not use when your promises are interdependent) then return this collections as an individual or all at once through using destructuring.

```
const [
    adminData,
    featuredData,
    sidebarData,
    watchNowData,
    interviewsData,
    categoryData,
    headlinesData,
] = await Promise.all([
    getDocs(query(collection(db, "admin"))),
    getDocs(query(collection(db, "featured"))),
    getDocs(query(collection(db, "sidebar"))),
    getDocs(query(collection(db, "watchNow"))),
    getDocs(query(collection(db, "interviews"))),
    getDocs(query(collection(db, "category"))),
    getDocs(query(collection(db, "headlines"))),
]);
//… your extracting collections will go on here
return {
  props: {
    admin: admin,
    featured: featured,
    sidebar: sidebar,
    watchNow: watchNow,
    interviews: interviews,
    category: category,
    headlines: headlines,
  },
};
```

You can get the collection in the `HomePage` component through its props:

```
export default function HomePage({
    admin,
    featured,
    sidebar,
    watchNow,
    interviews,
    category,
    headlines,
    ...props
}) {
    return (
        //… drill destructed props into the corresponding components
    );
}
```

You could also try collecting promises into one object and destructing them after Promise.all().
For more about Promise.all [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)